# Array filtering with Array.filter

Tags: javascript

I have two code examples right here:

Number 1:

```
const cars = ['toyota', 'nissan', 'chevy', 'ford'];
const yearOfProducing = [2008, 1998, 2018, 2013];

const dates = cars.map((model, index)=> ({
    model,
    yearOfProducing: yearOfProducing[index]
}));

const filteredCars = dates.filter(el => {
    const yearOfProducing = el.yearOfProducing;
    return yearOfProducing.includes(1998) && yearOfProducing.includes(2018);
});
const filteredCars1 = filteredCars.map(el => el.model);
console.log(filteredCars1);
```

Number 2:

```
const kinds = ['mangosteen', 'durian', 'lychee', 'carambola'];
const years = [[2017, 2018], [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020], [2020], [2019, 2020]];

const fruits = kinds.map((kind, index) => ({
  kind,
  years: years[index]
}));

const filteredFruites = fruits.filter(el => {
  const years = el.years;
  return years.includes(2017) && years.includes(2018);
});
const filteredKinds1 = filteredFruites.map(el => el.kind);
console.log(filteredKinds1);
```

First one doesn't work at all for some reason, while second is doing just fine. It seems a bit weird to me as they are built fully identical, any ideas why that could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
const yearOfProducing = [2008, 1998, 2018, 2013];
```

and

```
const years = [[2017, 2018], [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020], [2020], [2019, 2020]];
```

Have different structures, 2nd one has nested arrays...

If you fix it like:

```
const yearOfProducing = [[2008], [1998, 2018], [2018], [2013]];
```

Also take note I added [`1998, 2018]` beacuse your codintion is:

```
return yearOfProducing.includes(1998) && yearOfProducing.includes(2018);
```

It will work:

```js
const cars = ['toyota', 'nissan', 'chevy', 'ford'];
const yearOfProducing = [[2008], [1998, 2018], [2018], [2013]];

const dates = cars.map((model, index)=> ({
    model,
    yearOfProducing: yearOfProducing[index]
}));

const filteredCars = dates.filter(el => {
    const yearOfProducing = el.yearOfProducing;
    return yearOfProducing.includes(1998) && yearOfProducing.includes(2018);
});
const filteredCars1 = filteredCars.map(el => el.model);
console.log(filteredCars1);
```

If you are looking of OR not AND with `[[2008], [1998], [2018], [2013]];`:

```
const yearOfProducing = el.yearOfProducing;
        return yearOfProducing.includes(1998) || yearOfProducing.includes(2018);
```

```js
const cars = ['toyota', 'nissan', 'chevy', 'ford'];
const yearOfProducing = [[2008], [1998], [2018], [2013]];

const dates = cars.map((model, index)=> ({
    model,
    yearOfProducing: yearOfProducing[index]
}));

const filteredCars = dates.filter(el => {
    const yearOfProducing = el.yearOfProducing;
    return yearOfProducing.includes(1998) || yearOfProducing.includes(2018);
});
const filteredCars1 = filteredCars.map(el => el.model);
console.log(filteredCars1);
```

Otherwise it will produce 0 matches, its unclear what outcome you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example *yearOfProducing* array is holding some integers while in second example *years* array is actually array of arrays. In first example, yearOfProducing is holding a number and in this line:

```
return yearOfProducing.includes(1998) && yearOfProducing.includes(2018);
```

yearOfProducing can not be 1998 and 2018 at the same time.